# How to access prototype's properties in Java Script with ES6 class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have been looking for a while for an answer and never found one. Thought I'd post my question here.

In Java Script, when we create an object constructor like so:

```
function Car(speed){
  this.speed = speed;
  this.position = 0;
}

Car.prototype.move = function(){
  this.position++
}
```

then we can access the prototype's properties like so:

```
console.log(Car.prototype)
// will output: Car { move: [Function] }
```

But when we declare the Car constructor like so (with ES6 classes)

```
class Car{
  constructor(speed) {
   this.speed = speed;
   this.position = 0;
  }

  move(){
    this.position++:
  }
}
```

then strangely when we do this we get an empty object:

```
console.log(Car.prototype)
// will output: Car { }
```

From what I read, all properties declared in a ES6 class outside of the constructor method are assigned on the prototype of the object. So why can't we access the properties of the prototype using console.log(Car.prototype)?

I also know it is part of the prototype because when I do this, it works:

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Car.prototype));
// output [ 'constructor', 'move' ]
```

So I know the `move` method is assigned to the prototype.

I just wonder why can't we access those properties using Objet.prototype like when we declare the constructor in a function instead of in a ES6 class?

Did I missed something, is this a bug?

I'm working in Node.js, if this information might be helpful

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm not using a browser I'm working in Node.js. I will update my question to specify that this is for Node.js

Comment: `console.log(Car.protoype)` does not output `Car { }`, for me at least. It outputs `{constructor: ƒ, move: ƒ} constructor: class Car, move: ƒ move(), __proto__: Object`

Comment: I tried my code in Safari and same result. I get `Car {  } ` when I use ES6 class

Comment: What specific problem are you trying to solve? Also might want to look at prototype of `new Car()`

Comment: @charlietfl I'm trying to teach some students that the ES6 class is just another syntax for inheritance and that under the hood, it is the same thing as with a function constructor. But when I tried to prepare my demonstration about the prototype object, I stumbled upon this problem and I'm trying to figure out why. Did I miss something and in the end is there some fundamental differences between the 2 approaches?

Comment: It may be that the prototype properties from an ES6 class are not set to enumerable in some environments.  You may try `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Car.prototype))`.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes when I do this `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Car.prototype))` it works, I'm simply wondering why `Car.prototype` won't work. I'll try to access the enumerable property of the prototype and see if this is the issue. It makes sense

Comment: @jfriend00 You were right! The enumerable property of the prototype properties are set to false when the object is constructed using the ES6 class. That explains why! If you put this an an answer I'll vote for it! This is the answer I was looking for. Good catch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the ES6 class declaration, it does put the methods on the prototype, but they may not be enumerable, thus a regular enumeration such as `console.log(Car.prototype)` will not display them.

You can see everything that is there with `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Car.prototype))` or other such Object methods that will show you everything that is there.